# Dovecot/Postfix: How to enforce an intial syntax check on user name before querying LDAP for authentication?

Tags: ldap, dovecot

I have a Postfix/Dovecot setup and use OpenLDAP as the user/password backend. Users must login with their fully-qualified email address as their username due to virtual hosting and hence the domain part is necessary for authentication, i.e. usernames look like `<local-part>@<fqdn-domain>`.

However, there are constant attacks which try to authenticate with usernames without a domain part. As this leads to an invalid DN inside the LDAP query, my logs are spilled with a lot of errors messages due to an invalid LDAP DN.

**Is there any configuration option which allows Dovecot to enforce some initial syntax checks on the provided user name and if that fails, Dovecot shortcuts the authentication process with an immediate deny response instead of querying the LDAP server and then failing?**

The LDAP configuration in Dovecot is

```
uris = ldapi://%2frun%2fopenldap%2fslapd.sock
auth_bind = yes
auth_bind_userdn = uid=%n,ou=users,o=%d,dc=my-host,dc=my-domain,dc=my-tld
base = ou=users,o=%d,dc=server,dc=my-host,dc=my-domain,dc=my-tld
```

As you can see, my LDAP setup uses so-called "junction points" to provide different sub-branches in the DIT for the different hosted domains. (The `o=%d`-part in the DN.) According to [Dovecot Configuration Manual - User variables](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/config_file/config_variables/#user-variables), `%d` is empty if the username has no domain-part after the `@`.

When an attacker tries to authenticate with a incomplete username, this leads to superfluous error messages in my logs like

```
Dec 26 16:25:54 server dovecot[24946]: auth: Error: ldap(root,187.205.80.184): ldap_bind() failed: Invalid DN syntax
```

Here an attacker from 187.205.80.184 tried to authenticate as user `root` and Dovecot tried to look up `uid=root,ou=users,o=,dc=my-host,dc=my-domain,dc=my-tld` which obviously is invalid, because there is nothing after `o=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Dovecot v2.2.33, you could set a default domain using [conditionals](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/config_file/config_variables/#conditionals):

`%{if;%d;eq;;example.com;%d}`

This is:

- `if` use conditionals
- `%d` *value 1* to compare
- `eq` *operator*: string equality
- empty *value 2* for the comparison
- `example.com` resulting value if the condition is `true`; when `%d` equals empty string (default)
- `%d` resulting value if the condition is `false`; when `%d` is set (non-empty)

You can use it in the LDAP configuration instead of `%d`:

```
uris = ldapi://%2frun%2fopenldap%2fslapd.sock
auth_bind = yes
auth_bind_userdn = uid=%n,ou=users,o=%{if;%d;eq;;example.com;%d},dc=example,dc=com
base = ou=users,o=%{if;%d;eq;;example.com;%d},dc=example,dc=com
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution myself which does not require conditionals in variables and hence also works for older Dovecot versions. In the specific case of the `%d`-variable the following configuration directives do the trick

```
auth_realms = <vhosted-dom-1> <vhosted-dom-2> ... <vhosted-domain-n>
auth_default_realm = nowhere.notld
```

The first line is a space-separated list of the supported authentication realms. Depending on which SASL authentication method a client chooses, this informs the client about the existing authentication realms. Of course, this does not prevent (dumb) scripted attackers from still using usernames without a domain-part. However, it is good style to have that configuration being set properly.

The second line defines the default realm (or domain in my case) which Dovecot appends automatically, if the client fails to provide one. Here I set it to the made-up name `nowhere.notld`. The value does not really matter, it should only be different from any real domain.

*Final note:* Of course, this does not prevent log message about failing authentication attempts. But that is fine. However, it prevents fatal errors from LDAP due to invalid DNs. Instead, there are proper warnings from Dovevot about failed authentications.